# Creating a periodic sequence from a given subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

You are given the odd elements of an infinite binary sequence:

$$ a_1, a_3, a_5, \dots $$

You have to add even elements $a_2,a_4,a_6,\dots$ such that the resulting sequence is periodic (i.e, a binary representation of a rational number).

Is this always possible?

Comment: There are uncountably many binary sequences $a_1,a_3,a_5,\dots$, and only countably many representations of rationals, so the answer must be No. [Well, there is a minor detail: how many cases are there where two odd sequences could be completed to the *same* rational number, but there are only  countably many of those.]

Comment: @almagest I do not understand your last comment. Why can't you have uncountably many odd sequences completed to the same rational number?

Comment: Think about it! The only way you can get that is by exploiting the usual $\dots 01111\dots=\dots1000\dots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the resulting sequence is periodic with period $T$. Consider a shift of $2T$: being even, it puts odd elements to odd positions, that is, works as a shift on our initial subsequence $a_1, a_3, a_5, \dots$, which consequently must itself be periodic. If it is not, then the resulting sequence can't be either.

The countability argument by @almagest is indeed much stronger. Say, you'd start with a subsequence of numbers at *quadratic* positions $a_1,a_4,a_9,a_{16}\dots$, or better yet, at positions which are powers of 2: $a_1,a_2,a_4,a_8\dots$; then what? Would you always be able to complete this into a periodic sequence? No, you won't.